# Different Output From Same PyQuery Object

Tags: python, scrapy, pyquery

I am using scrapy in order to crawl a web site.

```
with open('test.html', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
```

With this block I am writing body to a file. When I open the file I can see many "a" tag.

When I print the same thing with print. It shows only two "a" tags

```
print response.body
```

Do you have any idea what is happening here?

Comment: I think this depends on the site you are crawling.

Comment: Did you try to `write`/`print` at the same time?

Comment: These codes are both in parse method. So, response doesn't change in same parse method.

Comment: How it can be depend on the site if scrapy cannot run javascript code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. The crawled website has second `<html>` tag in a combobox.

I was using PyQuery and if there is any problem with tags in html structure PyQuery is not working.

Now I have changed my selector to xpath and now it finds all a tags in the html.